# How can I add multiple curly brackets over a list?

Tags: enumerate, itemize, brackets

How can I add curly brackets like this?

[image]

This is so far my code....

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item Hello
    \item Hi
    \item Good-bye
    \item Bye
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain this with `blkarray`. It defines a new column type, `\BAenum`, which automatically inserts the row number. With the `etoolbox` package, we can customise the formatting of this number to add a pair of parentheses:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array, blkarray}
\setlength\BAextrarowheight{4pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theBAenumi}{(}
\appto{\theBAenumi}{)}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{blockarray}{\BAenum p{4cm}c}
\begin{block}{\BAenum p{4cm} c \Right{\}}{\qquad Type 1}}
  Hello and some more text. & \\
   Hi \\
\end{block}
\begin{block}{\BAenum p{4cm}c\Right{\}}{\qquad Type 2}}
   Good-bye\,! Fare thee well\,! & \\
  Bye \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}%

\end{document}
```

[image]